# Website shows 502 only on some pages

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

On this site:

http://www.seleconlight.com

everything is fine

On this url:

http://www.seleconlight.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=shop.flypage.p3&category_id=8&product_id=21

most people get an error 502 bad request.
- I do not get that error from my home DSL connection, and the site is in a data center
- I get an error on my smartphone, webpagetest.org and websitepulse.com
- None of these clients appear in the web server's apache log.

Normally a Bad gateway error indicates a network in between? How can this be for some pages, but not for others?

On further investigation I found a page that can be reproduced to cause the error, even with  the offending code removed:

```
http://www.seleconlight.com//index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.p1&category_id=121&product_id=74
```

I have the following test details with Webpagetest:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130122_BZ_12S8/1/details/ shows a 502 error

Details show:

```
URL: http://www.seleconlight.com//index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.p1&category_id=121&product_id=74
Host: www.seleconlight.com
IP: 23.62.236.155
Error/Status Code: 502
Initiated By: 
Start Offset: 0.214 s
DNS Lookup: 159 ms
Initial Connection: 54 ms
Time to First Byte: 1675 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 0.2 KB
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.5 KB
Request Headers:

GET //index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.p1&category_id=121&product_id=74 HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; PTST 2.345)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.seleconlight.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Content-Length: 0
Expires: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 23:15:58 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 23:15:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Note the IP address is 23.62.236.155, reverse DNS: a23-62-236-155.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com whereas the domain is actually on 120.138.27.252
```

Comment: Maybe something in your error.log?

Comment: no, I have a specific error and access log for this site and my smartphoen ip address does not appear in there. I also checked error.log and for other_vhosts.access.log

Comment: Upstream probelm on amazon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a component beween your server and the client has some trouble e.g. a loadbalancer. By the way I get also a `502 Bad Gateway` http error without any data.

It is possible that this special url or a joomla plugin makes some trouble. But I cannot imagine that if you don't get any errors in your apache logs.

Comment: Agree, but we do not employ a load balancer - only a single server.

I do find it very confusing in regards to the logs as well, but as per above, I have checked many times.

Comment: I found through trial and error it can indeed be fixed, by stopping the page build half way. The code I'm digging into is quite old. It must be crashing apache without a log being written

Answer (score 8):

Although another answer has already been accepted, my answer may still be useful for someone.
I've seen 502 errors returned by Akamai when:
1. The total size of your headers exceeds 8K
2. The size of the individual header (usually a cookie) exceeds 4K.

Try reducing the size of your cookies first. This is a better option.
You CAN ask Akamai to increase the supported size of the headers but I would advise against this.

Comment: Thanks again. In fact the problem was that a cookie was created ca 20 times and injected into the header. Once this was reduced to 1, it worked. It may have been the doubling up or that the size was exceeded, but I doubt it reached 4k

Comment: Thank you. In my case because client was setting custom user-agent, npm package which we use for CSP was repeating CSP headers 3 times. Considering size of CSP for a big site, this can go over 8K easily.

Comment: I fixed issue that I previously mentioned by checking my custom user-agent after helmet middleware and removing unnecessary legacy CSP headers. See https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/issues/110 for relevant discussion.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found that the website did set the same cookie about 20 times in a single request. Turning this off solved the problem with the Akamai proxy.